# html button to big/css not changing the size

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game in javascipt, html and css.  I just started, and one of the major challenges of the game is going to be making invisible buttons under text to make the text appear clickable.  Here is my code:

```html
<button type="button" style=visibility:hidden;font-family:monospace;font-size:12px></button>
         
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<p class="p1" style=position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;font-size:55px;font-family:monospace>
  HI
</p>
```

The button makes a blank space but it is not in the correct spot and shows up as 55 pixels big.  Please help

Comment: You'd probably have better results by using the `onclick` event of the `<p>`

Comment: ok, the only problem is that i have to make massive amounts of text and making so many <p> tags seems trivial

Comment: What do you mean by "make the text appear clickable"? Usually you can just use CSS for that (cursor:pointer), but maybe I misunderstand your intention.

Comment: You can use the `onclick` event on most any tag.  It seems weird that you want to click the text and have it click a button.  Technically, the `z-index` of your text element would make the button unclickable anyway.  I think the best thing to do would be to clarify exactly what you are looking for, as @Ynhockey's comment suggests.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion.  I need to be able to click the text to start some javascript code.

Comment: Your style attribute needs to be quoted. `style="visibility:hidden; .. etc"`

Comment: i did that and it gave the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you should do something like this. You don't have to worry about the location of the button.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .p1 {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        font-size:55px;
        font-family:monospace
    }
    .nolink {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000
    }

</style>


<script>
    function doSomething() {
        alert("say hi");
    }
</script> 


     <p class="p1">   
      HI, this <a class='nolink' href="javascript:void();" onclick="doSomething();return false;">text</a> is clickable
     </p>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/usndLuqe/4/

updated answer. isolated css

Comment: hmmm clever.  What would the best way to go about eliminating any sign it is a hyperlink?

Comment: im just gonna do it inline because i only need to do it 15 or so times

Comment: That will work ...  Though a class might come in handy. That way you can always apply it if another occasion pops up. Good luck!